# Elasticsearch mongodb river script in index doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I'm trying to change few fields strings using javascript.

For example take only the last part of the `URL` taken from `mongo` through the river so in elasticsearch I'll have only the end of it.

When creating the index `(using curl)` I added under "options" the following script:

```
"script": "ctx.document.shorturl = ctx.document.url.substr(-4);delete ctx.document.url;
```

I tried some manipulations such as adding `\"...\"` or use `ctx['doc']['url']` and others but nothing seems to work.

I always get only url field with the full url (shorturl is not created at all).

Can anyone suggest what is the right syntax to make it work?

Another thing I need to do is combine to fields - `lat & long`, to one "location" field in order to use it in Kibana, can anyone suggest the right script for that? (create new field called "location" which contain both field `"lat" & "long"` with comma between them).
Thanks.

Comment: lang-javascript plugin is installed and scripting is enabled...

Answer (score 0):

You did `substring(-4)`, hence it will return the whole string. You should use `substring(4)` instead:

```
ctx.document.shorturl = ctx.document.url.substr(4);delete ctx.document.url;
```